# ctypes error expected LP_mytpe instance instead of LP_mytype

Tags: ctypes

I am using ctypes to use a c library in python called libmylib. when I try calling a function from there I am getting the following error:

```
ArgumentError: argument 1: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: expected LP_mytype instance instead of LP_mytype
```

the code that generates this error looks like this:

```
arg1 = libmylib.create_mytype_p()
libmylib.myfunc(arg1)
```

`create_mytype` returns a pointer to `mytype` i.e `LP_mytype` and `myfunc` takes in a pointer to `mytype` as I have defined it to be so:

```
mytype_p = POINTER(mytype)
mylib.myfunc.argtypes = [mytype_p]
```

`mytype` is a ctypes Structure that mirrors a struct I have defined in `libmylib`.

I think what this is saying is that it is looking for an "instance" of `mytype_p` i.e `arg1.contents` or just a `mytype` object however clearly that is not what I told it to explect so if this is the case then why is this happening?

If I am misunderstanding this then I have no idea what it is expecting as an argument type and some clarification on that would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After inspecting the types using pdb I noticed that the module prefixes were different. Turns out I had a duplicate definition of the same structure that was redefining the previous one imported from another module. Unfortunately python hid this fact from me by only showing the type, without the module owner of the type.